# PHP loading large csv file - memory issues

Tags: php, memory

I have the following code

```
$file="postcodes.csv";
$csv= file_get_contents($file);
$array = array_map("str_getcsv", explode("\n", $csv));
$json = json_encode($array);
print_r($json);
```

postcodes.csv is 603MB in size, so a large file.

In php.ini, if I have

> memory_limit=1024M

I get the error

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 256 bytes) in ...

If I increase the memory limit to 2056, I get the error

> Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 1919680512) (tried to allocate
>   36 bytes) in...

It is similar if I change it to -1.

So how can I load this csv file without having memory issues?

Thanks

Comment: Unless you actually *need* all the rows in memory at once (which is rare), I suggest processing them in parts - worst case "read one row, process it, output, repeat."

Comment: I agree with the above, but for the sake of analysing this: Is PHP reading that in with each character converted to your native CPU word length? If so, try increasing your `memory_limit` to at least 4 * or 8 * the number of characters in the input file, depending on your architecture, and see whether that helps. Disclaimer: I've not done file-reading in PHP yet.

Comment: Lines 2-4 basically mean: Hold all of the ~600 MB of data in memory at least three times at once (as string, as array, as JSON string). That’s actually a great example how not to do a thing like that. Sorry. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of getting the full file into a variable, parsing it for newlines and then do `str_getcsv` on each array element.

Depending on what you are after, one full `json` containing all values from each line or multiple `json` strings one for each csv line.

```
$h = fopen("postcodes.csv",);

if ($h !== FALSE) {
    $str ='';
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE) {

        $str .= json_encode($data); // add each json string to a string variable, save later
        // or
        $array[]=$data;     
    }
}
fclose($h);

$finalJsonString = json_encode($array);
```

I wouldn't recommend that you `print_r` an entire `array` or `json` object of that size since it would be difficult to follow.

Answer (score 2):

You can read your file line by line.

For example,

```
$file="postcodes.csv";
$array = array();
if (($handle = fopen($file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $array[]=$data;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
$json = json_encode($array);
print_r($json);
```

But memory problem still can happen if you have really a lot of data and your array is too big

Answer (score 2):

The answer is simple you need to increase memory_limit in php.ini, because files have 603MB, but using all this function in code creates some structures in memory from json data and this is more than 603MB. Alernativley you can optimize memory usage changing code, but your question is how to increase memory limit.

Answer (score 1):

If you are reading a large file I would recommend using file pointer and `fgetcsv()` function and looping line by line rather than loading whole file.

Also, new line not necessarily mean end of the CSV row, `explode("\n", $csv)` may give you some unwanted results... It would be safer to use `fgetcsv()`